# Gluttonous Snake game code can't enter move function

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var zbImg = new Image();
zbImg.src = './image/zuobian.jpg';

var bgImg = new Image();
bgImg.src = './image/beijing.jpg';

var smImg = new Image();
smImg.src = './image/shangmian.png';

var stImg = new Image();
stImg.src = './image/shenti.png';

var xmImg = new Image();
xmImg.src = './image/xiamian.png';

var ybImg = new Image();
ybImg.src = './image/youbian.png';

function Snake() {

  this.cav = document.getElementById("cav");
  this.canvas = this.cav.getContext('2d');
  this.step = 25;
  this.width = 500;
  this.height = 500;

  this.stepW = this.width / this.step;
  this.stepH = this.height / this.step;

  this.snakeArr = []; //snake body
  this.foodArr = []; //store food






  //1, draw the game elements
  this.draw = function() {
    // paint background
    this.canvas.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    // paint snake

    // draw it
    this.drawFood = function() {
      if (this.foodArr.length != 0) {
        this.canvas.drawImage(stImg, this.foodArr[0].x * this.step, this.foodArr[0].y * this.step, this.step, this.step);
        return;
      }
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.stepW);
      var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.stepH);


      for (var i = 0; i < this.snakeArr.length; i++) {
        if (this.snakeArr[i].x == x && this.snakeArr[i].y == y)

        {
          this.drawFood();
          break;
        }
      }


      // not cover
      this.foodArr[0] = {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        Image: stImg
      }
      this.canvas.drawImage(
        stImg, this.foodArr[0].x * this.step, this.foodArr[0].y * this.step, this.step, this.step);

    }





    this.drawSnake = function() {

      // initial snake body
      if (this.snakeArr.length == 0) {

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          this.snakeArr[i] = {
            x: this.stepW / 2 + i - 2,
            y: this.stepH / 2,
            img: stImg,
            d: 'l'
          }
        }
        this.snakeArr[0].img = zbImg; //change to snake head pic 

      }
      for (var i = 0; i < this.snakeArr.length; i++) {
        this.canvas.drawImage(this.snakeArr[i].img,
          this.snakeArr[i].x * this.step,
          this.snakeArr[i].y * this.step,
          this.step,
          this.step);
      }

    }
    this.drawFood();
    this.drawSnake();



    console.log(5);

  }
  //2, make snake move
  this.move = function() {

    document.onkeydown = function(event) {
      var event = event || window.event;
      var code = event.keyCode;

      console.log(7);
      console.log(code);


      switch (code) {
        case 37:
          This.snakeArr[0].d = 'l';
          This.snakeArr[0].img = zbImg;
          break;
        case 38:
          This.snakeArr[0].d = 't';
          This.snakeArr[0].img = smImg;
          break;
        case 39:
          This.snakeArr[0].d = 'r';
          This.snakeArr[0].img = ybImg;
          break;
        case 40:
          This.snakeArr[0].d = 'b';
          This.snakeArr[0].img = xmImg;
          break;
      }
      console.log(This.snakeArr[0]);
    }
  }
  //3, make snake to die
  this.hit = function() {

  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html1>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>tangchishe</title>
    <style>
      #cav {
        background: red;
      }
    </style>
    <script src='./index.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {

        var snake = new Snake();
        snake.draw();
        snake.move();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="cav" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  </body>
</html1>
```

This picture is content I got after I run my code :

[image: this picture is content I got after I run my code]

this is the code I've written, it can appear snake and food when I run at browser, but code can't enter move function method. I use `console.log` print 5 before move function method and use `console.log` print 7 in move function method. finally google chrome browser console appear 5 and not appear 7
who can help me?
thank you very much

Comment: Do you have any console errors? Where is your Snake Class defined? I would suggest putting a breakpoint on the `snake.drew();` line and making sure the `snake` variable is what you expect it to be. If it is, then I would try calling your `.move` function and stepping through that code line-by-line until you have got a good error message or see what's going wrong.

Comment: i am not find console errors, But my complier is sublime trial edition，it dose  not have breakpoint, do you have some good complier for javascript can recommend to me   thank you

Comment: Use your browsers developer tools (typically F12 will launch them). You can set breakpoints there. I would also recommend Visual Studio Code or WebStorm for IDE's

Answer (score 0):

A couple things are going on here at first glance. You should, for starters, move your javascript to another file and load it into the page. But even if you don't, it looks like the javascript is just pasted at the end of the document and is not in "" tags. Also, why is the page surrounded with an "html1" tag? This should just be "html"

Comment: actually,  my html and javascript already separate to different files, I use tangchishe.html contain first segment code and use index.js contain second  second segment code.   I changed html1 to html. but it is still not print 7

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. It looks to me like you only call the draw() function when the window loads. This needs to be called regularly to update the canvas, perhaps with setInterval? As far as the event not firing, try changing it from document.onkeydown to window.onkeydown. It's a focus issue, from what I understand.